# how to write datetime <= (minus some days) in teradata case statement

Tags: datetime, teradata, case-statement, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have to write an sql query where I need to extract data for 30 days minus few days,

something like this, datetime <= -5 days

what is the best possible way I can write in teradata?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly 5 days based on a timestamp, e.g. 2021-09-24 13:42 -> 2021-09-19 13:42

```
 where timestamp_column <= current_timestamp - interval '5' day
```

Full days starting at midnight:

```
 where timestamp_column <= current_date - 5
```

Comment: Thank you! But, what if I am looking for data from last month and not current time_stamp. eg. 2021-09-31 00:00:00.000 minus 5days to 2021-08-26 00:00:00.000

Comment: Well, you did write that in your question. The last day of the previous month: `last_day(add_months(current_date,-1))`